# Tabs as views or Activity?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which requires nested tabs (tabs within tabs). Say for example one of my tabs is a message tab into which I have four tabs- inbox, compose, sent, trash. I have around 3-4 of such nested tabs in my app. I'm looking for a few suggestions whether to make these tabs separate activities or just views. I've read about this issue and I'm aware that this problem is very much specific to the need of an application. But as a beginner I'm skeptical about my approach. Initially I wasn't sure if I should have so many activities in my code as it would hamper the performance. As of now I've created the main tabs as separate activities and the nested tabs as views. For most of the inner tabs I only want a user to select from a list of options, though there are a couple of tabs which involve more user interaction. Can everything that can be achieved by an activity approach is possible via view approach? If so, then How? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you could make those nested tabs into different options menus for each of the parent tabs.  In each of your activities in the first tab menu, you can add this...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

and then implement a listener..

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.one: 
        case R.id.two:
        default:
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think that is the best way to offer more options to your users for each of the activities in your tab menu.  You could then access each one of these menus for whichever `TabActivity` the user is currently on.  They just have to push the default options button.

Comment: This occurred to me, but actually I'm an iPhone user so may be I'm not getting this right. Does it occur to an android user that he may have to press the menu button to access more options? I mean how will he know that there are more options for this tab?

Comment: I would think so.. I believe that is pretty standard knowledge for android users. Otherwise, as long as your ui isn't messy, its not necessarily a bad thing to have several activities, as long as your good about managing them, i.e. call finish() when your done using them. I would think there would be a better way of organizing your ui though..